# Query to return most recent data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For below example:

```
ID   Name   Date
1    A      2018-01-29
2    B      2018-01-29
3    A      2018-01-28
```

I am looking for a query to return me the 2nd row, which is `2 B 2018-01-29`

The selecting criteria is for all the most recent records, pick one that has the different name comparing to the previous date group.

So, from my example, the most recent date is `2018-01-29`, the candidate rows are Id:1 and Id:2, but I am picking Id:2 because it has Name: B, which is different from previous date's (2018-01-28) Name.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.  The way it works is, you post your query.  If it doesn't work, we can help you fix it.  At least try something!!!!

Comment: What if you have 5 rows with the same `Date`?Also did you try to use `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: @Sami, good point, then picking any one of the record is fine

Comment: Which version of SQL Server (can you use `LAG()`)? Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It would also be helpful to have a couple more examples with different data combinations.  It is, in principle, impossible to extrapolate from a single data point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(5), DATE DATE)

INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(1,'A','2018-01-29')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(2,'B','2018-01-29')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(3,'C','2018-01-29')
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(4,'A','2018-01-28')

SELECT TOP 1 ID,NAME,DATE 
FROM(
    SELECT *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATE DESC)RN 
    FROM @Tab
    )D
WHERE D.RN=1
    AND D.NAME NOT IN(
            SELECT NAME 
            FROM(
                SELECT *
                    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATE DESC)RN  
                FROM @Tab
                )D 
            WHERE RN>1)
```

**RESULT:**

```
ID  NAME    DATE
2   B       2018-01-29
```